# API won't return data (Google Sheets / App Script)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I believe that the problem is in the definitions of the **var's** for the creation of the `table.push`, for the correct path to the data as would the definitions of `var dia`, `var mes`, `var ano`, `var hora`, `var minuto`?

```
function CartolaPrazo() {
  var url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log(response)
  
  var table = [['dia','mês','ano','hora','minuto']];
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var r = results[i];
    var dia = r.fechamento.dia;
    var mes = r.fechamento.mes;
    var ano = r.fechamento.ano;
    var hora = r.fechamento.hora;
    var minuto = r.fechamento.minuto;
    table.push([dia,mes,ano,hora,minuto]);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 22, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI the response is not an array, so  your for loop won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't have an array of json objects but just one json object.
  Therefore, the loop in your code is unnecessary but also wrong since
  `results.length` is `null`.
- As a result, you will get only one row of data.

Assuming that the `url` you are using is what you want to get, this will give you the expected result:

```
function CartolaPrazo() {
  var url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var table = [['dia','mês','ano','hora','minuto']];
  var dia = results.fechamento.dia;
  var mes = results.fechamento.mes;
  var ano = results.fechamento.ano;
  var hora = results.fechamento.hora;
  var minuto = results.fechamento.minuto;
  table.push([dia,mes,ano,hora,minuto]);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 22, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `console.log(results)` not `console.log(response)`.

`response` holds an [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) object, which the console displays as `{}`.